# Linux Server and LAMP basic questions

Tags: networking, server, lamp

I am pretty new to the Linux environment. I have been asked to setup a Linux server and LAMP. I do have a background on network and windows server admin, however when it gets to Linux servers, I don't know where to start.

Questions:

- Any good books or links for a newbie on how to administer a Linux server?
- Where is the setting for admin control on a Linux server, such as dns, dhcp, etc.?
- I googled a few things about LAMP, but I am not sure whether the required applications have already been installed.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Linux!

If you want a guide for Ubuntu Server, visit this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/, and choose your version. When you click on your version, you'll find an **Ubuntu Server Guide** link. I think that is an excellent and organized guide. There's a section for LAMP applications in it.

Since you're new to Linux and Ubuntu in general, there's an excellent guide called the [**Ubuntu Pocket Guide**](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html). I read this when I was beginning with Ubuntu (as a normal desktop user though) and it was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good books available through Amazon for admin of Ubuntu Server. I have [The Official Ubuntu Server Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081332) and it's pretty good; also there is [Ubuntu 12.04 Server: Administration and Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936280469) which would help.

I would recommend using the 12.04 Server LTS release. The installation will include options for setting up LAMP as part of the install process. The server versions do not install a desktop environment by default, but you can install one like Lubuntu or Xubuntu to have a light-weight desktop environment while you are learning your way through the system.