# Setting up Ubuntu web server?

Tags: server, dns, hosting

I've just purchased a cloud VPS and installed Ubuntu Server 13.04 on it and that is pretty much all of my Linux knowledge.

Can someone point me to the best up to date tutorial on setting up Ubuntu Web Server?

I need the standard stuff:

1. LAMP
2. FTP Server
3. Mail Server
4. DNS Server to point my domain to it.

Most of what I found were tutorials on setting up server on PC which is rather different then setting up server for productive purposes.

Also I'm paranoid that things might go south, can you tell me what is the routine of managing the server and more or less will I need to manage it at all after the setup?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I've found exactly what I was looking for, a perfect solution for all the starters out there who wonder how the hell can a normal person memorize all this linux commands :) here you go:

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-13.04-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/298741/52726. Take a look at that question.

Comment: @Alaa Thank you for your comment, I'm looking for a straight forward tutorial on setting up a web server on Ubuntu right now from my balcony while smoking a cigarette and drinking warm Nescaffe. Reading a book won't do it.

Comment: Haha, well with little knowledge in Linux, I doubt it'll be a clean experience, you'll eventually need to read. Anyways, maybe this is handy: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: mail server is whole domain on it own full of deep pits... consider getting it as a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For step-by-step instructions, take a look at [How to Setup a Dedicated Web Server](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/)

In this tutorial, you will learn about:

- Install  Ubuntu Server operating system.
- Install an OpenSSH server.
- A LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP) stack is going to be
  installed.
- Install a firewall to protect your server from unauthorized access.

For more information about FTP and bind DNS see [Create a web server with Linux](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialWebSiteConfig.html)

<sup>Source:[Net Tutts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already found this tutorials on Nettuts+ but they are very butchered, as I said this are written probably with home PC server in mind not a VPS or Dedicated server, I know how to install most of this things but the hard part is DNS server (Bind) and Mail Server installation and configuration, I need tutorials that include those segments.

Comment: I added another link in my answer, that talks about Bind and DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up LAMP and FTP is an easy task. Execute the following commands and just select FTP and LAMP:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo  tasksel
```

For a DNS server i suggest `dnsmasq` or `bind`. Where `dnsmasq` is easier to setup and should suffice for simple configurations.

But when it comes to Mail (you need working DNS for mail to work), that's another story. 
I can suggest you the following walk through for setting up a mail server: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/

I also recommend you [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) (a web based admin interface) and a firewall (i prefer [shorewall](http://shorewall.net/)).

There are plenty of things that can be done wrong so take care what you do ;)

Good luck with your first Ubuntu server!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found out that LAMP can be installed with 2 copy-paste commands. But still no luck with Bind.